# Generating ASP.Net Pages on the fly

Tags: .net, asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting

Regarding [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4256104/337294), suppose the following scenario:

I have a ASP.Net Webforms site (www.example.com) with 2 pages: `default.aspx` and `result.aspx`.

- In `result.aspx` I have a label: "Result page"
- In `default.aspx` I have a text box and a button

The user types in his custom phrase (`Custom_User_Input_Text`) in the textbox and hits the submit button.

Now I want the user to be redirected to an "on the fly" generated page at: `www.example.com/Custom_User_Input_Text` which is actually `result.aspx`. (The user sees "Result page").

**Simply put**, I'd like to be able to do url rewriting programmatically.

*P.S I'm not the type of guy who asks for code. But I don't have a clue where to start.*

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you using?  What version of IIS will you be running this website on?

Comment: ASP.Net 3.5 or 4. IIS 7 or 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have IIS 7 the route to travel is the `HttpHandler`. 
If that is enough clue to start with, then we leave it with this, otherwise leave a comment.

PS. Do make sure, that the `Managed pipeline mode` setting (IIS-> Application Pools) is  on `Integrated mode`, so IIS passes all requests to your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it doable in a code-behind file? or should I modify IIS settings as well? I'm asking this to find out if my scenario is possible in shared hosting services.

Comment: Well, I believe in IIS 7 the integrated mode is the default mode. If not, just send your hosting provider a mail, it's not an abnormal setting. The HttpHandler thing is on your side, it's a class which you can add to your project, and just reference it in your web.config.

Comment: You can use an HTTP Handler in IIS 6 as well and in the Classic Pipeline Mode.

Comment: @Frazell Then he would have to make changes in IIS, which he can't.